# summernote rendering embed tweet

Tags: javascript, summernote

I have tweet I want to show it like embed a tweet in my website but whenever I paste the embed tweet in summer note is rendering to a different type as follows.

Original Embed Code

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">It’s all about the details. Now you can rearrange your photos while writing a Tweet. <a href="#">pic.twitter.com</a></p>&mdash; Twitter (@Twitter) <a href="https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/1171560988874891264?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">September 10, 2019</a></blockquote>
```

Rendered Code

```
<twitter-widget class="twitter-tweet twitter-tweet-rendered" id="twitter-widget-0" style="position: static; visibility: visible; display: block; transform: rotate(0deg); max-width: 100%; width: 500px; min-width: 220px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;" data-tweet-id="1171560988874891264"></twitter-widget>
```

Is anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not summernote problem, this problem is twitter script will auto convert `blockquote` tag to `twitter-widget` when script was loaded.

So you must store two versions of summernote content, one to preview direct on editor (which was converted to `twitter-widget`), and one raw version, that will be store into database.

I fixed this problem using function below:

```
convertTwitterSource(content) {
      let oldTwitterTags = this.rawContent.match(
        /<blockquote .*?>.*?<\/blockquote>/gi
      )

      if (oldTwitterTags) {
        oldTwitterTags.map(tag => {
          content = content.replace(
            /<twitter-widget .*?>.*?<\/twitter-widget>/i,
            tag
          )
        })
      }
      return content
}
```

- rawContent was manual save each time user typing to editor - This content wasn't converted
- content was getting from `$('#blog-summernote').summernote('code')` - This content was converted by external script,...